# representation of electrical circuits (paper)

Tags: circuit-analysis, spice

I'm looking for an old paper about a format for representation of electrical circuits using text, similar to some of the current netlist formats. Here is what I remember:

- it was written by Richard Stallman and (Gerald Sussman or Hal Abelson) from MIT;
- circa 1970 (with big error margin);
- it focused in writing software that solves electrical circuits in Lisp;
- it was likely typed using a teletype;
- it describes a simple yet effective language for representing analog electrical circuits.

I searched but cannot find it in my bookmarks and google. Does anyone knows any information about this?

Comment: Maybe [Heuristic techniques in computer-aided circuit analysis](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1083985) or [Forward reasoning and dependency-directed backtracking in a system for computer-aided circuit analysis](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0004370277900297)?

Comment: That's old technology. Are you able to use something like Visio? If you wish to use a programming language, look into [Circuitikz](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/circuitikz/) that's a package for \$\LaTeX\$.

Comment: I'm interested in the particular format they describe, not in the software itself.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is actually "Heuristic techniques in computer-aided circuit analysis". I think it was simpler than that. I will keep searching and get back here if I find something.

Comment: I think you're also trying to get sources for an underlying research problem. Might be a good idea to post that problem as question here, too! "How can I (efficiently) represent {linear, nonlinear} circuits with a domain-specific programming language so that they become analyzable trivially?"

Comment: Not really. I'm trying to build easy tools for circuit analysis and play with models for discrete components (transistors, capacitors, etc). I'm not a researcher, just a curious.

Comment: Here is a "public" version of "Heuristic techniques in computer-aided circuit analysis":  https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/5803/AIM-328.pdf

Comment: Google Scholar, Research Gate, your university's digital library, or other websites with a database for research papers and academic journals might be able to help you out with looking up the authors and seeing what they've written.

Comment: You won't find an easier tool with lots of wire voltage current, device trace power options and built in models http://tinyurl.com/y4xmq52a  explore all the menu options and right mouse  . drag/drop/rotate  add movable traces http://tinyurl.com/y2a3rezr  make any variable a slider on rt screen  like Vin , R value C etc eg http://tinyurl.com/y57snzf5

Comment: or  555 circuits http://tinyurl.com/y5tqsfuw  FIle>export as text> to see simple netlist format

Comment: Oh, such a great tool! I wish I had it back in college days. Life could have been much easier. Does this also simulates lossy-TL?

Answer (score 1):

> In 1971, near the end of his first year at Harvard, he became a programmer at the MIT Artificial Intelligence Laboratory [...]

> While working (starting in 1975) as a research assistant at MIT under Gerry Sussman,[18] Stallman published a paper (with Sussman) in 1977 on an AI truth maintenance system, called **dependency-directed backtracking**.[22] This paper was an early work on the problem of intelligent backtracking in constraint satisfaction problems. As of 2009, the technique Stallman and Sussman introduced is still the most general and powerful form of intelligent backtracking.[23] The technique of constraint recording, wherein partial results of a search are recorded for later reuse, was also introduced in this paper.[23]

Full text PDF of bolded paper: http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/6255/AIM-380.pdf

As Renan also mentioned in the comments, there is also a slightly older paper: [Heuristic techniques in computer-aided circuit analysis](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1083985) ([full text PDF](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/5803/AIM-328.pdf)).

Comment: I reached the conclusion that what I was looking for is "Heuristic techniques in computer-aided circuit analysis". I had to re-read both papers to get my memory-backup restored. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

First, thank you all for the answers and comments.

I was looking for what is in example 1 of "Heuristic techniques in computer-aided circuit analysis".

[image: Example 1]

This is a great tool to actually represent circuits for analysis. A simple, expressive and concise language. This is what I had on my poor memory. What I also had on my mind was to reimplement the program they describe in some modern Lisp environment and see what I get.

Thank you all.

Comment: How is this better than a SPICE netlist? For 11 components, a SPICE netlist is 11 lines...plus a couple more to make it a subcircuit.

Comment: This is the source code of an actual program I can feed in some sort of interpreter and see it running step by step. A NETLIST feed into a numerical solver'd give me a set of numbers without me having any idea about how these numbers were produced. Both have their own value in learning and research.